# Can you update the custom close reason regarding software engineering questions?

Tags: support, close-reasons

Currently, there is a custom off-topic reason here that reads:

> Software engineering questions are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour).

Following our rebranding, it should be closer to:

> Questions about **software engineering and working within the systems development life cycle** are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

This changed close reason incorporates the improved Software Engineering tagline (`Software Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professionals, academics, and students working within the systems development life cycle who care about creating, delivering, and maintaining software responsibly.`) and changes the link from the tour to the more comprehensive /help/on-topic page to help visitors get a much better understanding of the scope of Software Engineering.

Feel free to wordsmith the content, but I do think that linking to /help/on-topic is preferred to /tour.